# How to use ROW_NUMBER() along with aggregate functions?

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I have the following scenario in my SQL query. I have to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in my query, where some aggregate functions also are used to get the result.

```
SELECT 
    @TotalRequests = ReportCount.TotalCount,
    @TotalTimeToRespond = ReportCount.TotalTimeToRespond,
    @TotalRequestsHavingQnA = ReportCount.TotalRequestsHavingQnA,
    @ResponseCompliance = ReportCount.ResponseCompliance,
    @TotalSubmissions = ReportCount.TotalSubmissions
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TotalCount = Count(1),
         TotalTimeToRespond = SUM(Datediff(DAY, DCR.DateReceivedInCB, DCR.DueDate)),
         TotalRequestsHavingQnA = SUM(CASE
                                         WHEN DCR.NoOfQuestionsAsked IS NULL
                                                    OR DCR.NoOfQuestionsAsked = 0 THEN 0
                                              ELSE 1
                                            END),
         ResponseCompliance = Sum(CASE
                                          WHEN DCR.NoOfQuestionsAsked IS NULL
                                                OR DCR.NoOfQuestionsAsked = 0 THEN 0
                                          ELSE ( Cast(DCR.NoOfQuestionsAnswered AS DECIMAL) * 100 ) / Cast(DCR.NoOfQuestionsAsked AS DECIMAL)
                                        END),
         TotalSubmissions = Sum(CASE
                                        WHEN DCR.DateSubmitted IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                      END),
               rowNumber = Row_number()
                             OVER (
                               PARTITION BY DCR.callref
                               ORDER BY DCR.DateSubmitted DESC)
     FROM   
         DimCBComparisonReport DCR
     INNER JOIN 
         DimClientLoc DCL ON DCR.ClientLocKey = DCL.ClientLocKey
     WHERE  
         Ltrim(Rtrim(DCL.LocId)) IN (SELECT PARAM
                                     FROM Fn_splitparam(@LocationIdList, ','))
         AND (CASE
                WHEN @EnabledDateType = 'D' THEN DCR.DueDate
                       ELSE DCR.DateSubmitted
              END) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         AND DCL.ContractId = @ContractRef
         AND DCR.EmployeeKey IS NOT NULL) ReportCount
WHERE  
    ReportCount.rowNumber = 1
```

So here I am getting an exception like :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure etl_CaseBuilder_get_Location_Compliance_Summary, Line 41
>   Column 'DimCBComparisonReport.CallRef' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: Your select query will return only one record you can directly assign to variables you don't need `row_number`. If you are trying to achieve something else then explain

Comment: ...or `group by` is lost

Comment: I've voted to close this request, because it is unclear what the query is supposed to do. What is it you want to achieve with `ROW_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the rest of your columns in that query are aggregate without  being windowed functions. I'd change them all to be windowed functions (e.g. `sum() over (partition by x) as [Field]`) and then change it to a select distinct, see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` in a `MAX`/`MIN`. Example below:

```sql
Row_number()
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY MAX(DCR.callref)
    ORDER BY MAX(DCR.DateSubmitted) DESC
  )
```